# How to listen for event passed from parent to child in polymer.dart

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I am trying to pass an event from a parent to child in Polymer 1.0.0-rc2 in Dart. The problem is that I do not know how to go about listening for the event in the child. I've tried to put the on-control-panel-refire attribute in the dom-module in the `notation_view.html` file, and calling handle button from there, but it didn't work. What is the proper way to listen for this event? I know that `on-control-panel-button-pressed` is working well.

notation_view.dart

```
@PolymerRegister('notation-view')
class NotationView extends PolymerElement {

  NotationView.created() : super.created();

  @reflectable
  handleButton(Event e, var detail) {
    print("received");
  }
}
```

main_app.dart

```
@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  @reflectable
  refire(Event e, var detail) {
    querySelector('notation-view').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("control-panel-refire",
        detail: {'name' : detail["button-id"]}));
  }
```

main_app.html

```
<link rel="import" href="notation_view.html">

<dom-module id="main-app">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <notation-view id="notation-view"></notation-view>
    <control-panel id="control-panel" on-control-panel-button-pressed="refire"></control-panel>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

notation_view.html

```
<dom-module id="notation-view" >
    <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
    </style>

    <template>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
    </template>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this but I think instead of

```
   querySelector('notation-view').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("control-panel-refire",
    detail: {'name' : detail["button-id"]})); 
   }
```

it should be

```
   new PolymerDom(root).querySelector('notation-view').fire("control-panel-refire",
    detail: {'name' : detail["button-id"]}));
   }
```

You can cast the result of `querySelector()` to `PolymerElement` or `NotationView` if the analyzer complains about the unknown `fire()` method.

To listen to an event use

```
@PolymerRegister('notation-view')
class NotationView extends PolymerElement {

  NotationView.created() : super.created();

  @reflectable
  handleButton(Event e, var detail) {
    print("received");
  }

  @Listen('control-panel-refire')
  void handleControlPanelRefire(CustomEvent e, [_] /* or `Map detail` instead of [_] */) {
    // handle event
  }

  // alternatively
  EventSubscription _controlPanelRefireSubscr;
  attached() {
    super.attached();
    _controlPanelRefireSubscr = this.on['control-panel-refire'].listen((event) {
      // handle event 
    });
  }

  detached() {
    super.detached();
    _controlPanelRefireSubscr?.cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: `The null object does not have a method '_badUpgrade'.`

I'm getting this error, I assume this means that either the NotationView is failing to upgrade, or it isn't finding the NotationView. The error is from the `PolymerDom(root).querySelector()` line.

Comment: Is this in Firefox or Chrome. What suggesion of my answer did you use, the `@Listen()`?

Comment: I'm using Dartium. I was planning on using `@Listen()`, but I don't think the problem has to do with that.

Comment: Did you or did you not add `@Listen()`?

Comment: I didn't use `@Listen()`, but the problem persists when I do.

Comment: What Dart version are you using? Might be https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/634

Comment: Ah, I'm 1.0.0-rc2, probably the same problem, thanks.